# Add to Listbox and Identify duplicate words after the slash

Tags: c#

Hello I have this LINQ code for adding items to my listbox

```
        LB.BeginUpdate();
        LB.Items.AddRange(Regex.Matches(Clipboard.GetText(), httpPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            .Cast<Match>().Where(m => !LB.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item.Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(m => m.Value).ToArray());
        LB.EndUpdate();
        CountLinks();
```

I only want to add one link for each list of episode.
and I want to prevent adding againt to listbox if the word "Title1 or Title2" is already existed.

like this (this is the sample of episode links):

```
EPISODE 1:
    https://www.123.com/en-us/18026/Title1
    https://www.123.com/en-us/18025/Title1
    https://www.123.com/en-us/18024/Title1
    https://www.123.com/en-us/18023/Title1

EPISODE 2:
    https://www.123.com/en-us/28026/Title2
    https://www.123.com/en-us/28025/Title2
    https://www.123.com/en-us/28024/Title2
    https://www.123.com/en-us/28023/Title2
```

UPDATE:
here's the modified version with ideas by @Blindy

```
LB.Items.AddRange(Regex.Matches(Clipboard.GetText(), @"^(.*/([^/]*?))$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
       .Cast<Match>().Where(m => !LB.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item.Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
       .GroupBy(m => m.Groups[2].Value.Trim())
       .Select(grp => grp.First().Groups[1].Value).ToArray());
```

The only problem now is it keeps adding the same link.

Comment: "I don't want to add items if words are the same after slash the word "SameWords" I only want to get at least one of them." Can you rephrase that sentence in English, please? Or show exactly what you want and don't want to happen, with an example? Because right now I'm tempted to close your post as gibberish.

Comment: I've already edited.

Comment: Specifically `SameWords`? Is it multiple words (that sample text has plural for words)? A bit later you say you only want to add one link, what's forcing you to add more? Is there someone else we can talk to to get a better idea of what you're trying to do, with clear and concise examples?

Comment: Is the "like this" part supposed to be the passing examples? Or the failing ones? Because in English, "like this" would show an example of what you're expecting, but they all have the same `SameWords` part that you seem to maybe want to avoid?

Comment: No the word "SameWords" are the same.
wait I'll update my example links

Comment: The same ***as what***?? You can't just say "the same", it's an expression that specifies a relationship between **two** entities.

Comment: I've update my question and added example of what I want  to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should give you what you want, ie the first link for a specific title (the last part of the link) from a string (`s`) of new-line-separated links (and other garbage):

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"^(.*/([^/]*?))$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => m.Success)
        .GroupBy(m => m.Groups[2].Value.Trim())
        .Select(grp => grp.First().Groups[1].Value)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Also `GroupBy` is very inefficient for what you want, I recommend getting morelinq for its `DistinctBy` operation.

Comment: Wow it worked. but only the problem is, when I click the button again, it keeps adding the link with the same Title again. How to prevent it?

Comment: Store the inserted titles in a `HashSet<string>` and before selecting add a `.Where(grp => !set.Contains(m.Groups[2].Value.Trim()))` to exclude titles you already added.

Comment: I'll update my post and insert the updated code.
The only problem is keeps adding the same link

Comment: Do what I said above.

Comment: I have tried but adding the existing links from Listbox to hashset. and do what you said !hash.Contains..... but it's only adding all the links individually

Answer (score 0):

Alright. first of all thanks to @Blindy for helping me out to solved this problem.

So here's what I've got.

```
LB.BeginUpdate();
LB.Items.AddRange(Regex.Matches(cb, @"^(https://www.123.com(.*/([^/]*?)))$", 
RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
.Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
.GroupBy(m => m.Groups[3].Value.Trim())
.Select(grp => grp.First().Groups[1].Value).ToArray());
RemoveDuplicateItems();
LB.EndUpdate();
```

since I can't prevent adding the same link:
So I used this to remove duplicates before the EndUpdate of listbox

```
string[] arr = new string[LB.Items.Count];
LB.Items.CopyTo(arr, 0);

var dis = arr.Distinct();

LB.Items.Clear();
foreach (string s in dis)
{
LB.Items.Add(s);
}
```